# SWT drop cursor position on canvas

Tags: java, canvas, swt

I'm making a simple "paint" application in JAVA. I would have wanted that when the person clicks the canvas, and make a drag and drop, a listener get the drop cursor location, but I don't find how make a drop listener. How can I find the location of the cursor when the user stop his click?

I have the following code for the drag :

```
    Canvas paintC = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
    paintC.addDragDetectListener(new DragDetectListener() {
        public void dragDetected(DragDetectEvent arg0) {
            Point controlRelativePos = new Point(arg0.x, arg0.y);

            displayRelativePos1 = paintC.toDisplay(controlRelativePos);

            GC gc = new GC(paintC);

            gc.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));
            gc.fillRectangle(arg0.x, arg0.y, 90, 60);

        }
    });
```

Should I a drag function in order to get the latest position?

Edit: I've tried this, but it didn't work :

```
dropTarget.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
            displayRelativePos2 = dropTarget.getDisplay().getCursorLocation();

            hauteur = displayRelativePos2.y - displayRelativePos1.y;
            largeur = displayRelativePos2.x - displayRelativePos1.x;

            GC gc = new GC(paintC);
            gc.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
            gc.fillRectangle(displayRelativePos1.x, displayRelativePos1.y, largeur, hauteur);

            nbFormesAff = nbFormes +1;
            forme = "Rectangle" + nbFormesAff;
            pos = displayRelativePos1.x + ", " + displayRelativePos1.y +"\nhauteur:" + hauteur +" largeur:"+ largeur;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`DropTargetEvent` has `x` and `y` fields which contain the Display relative location of the cursor.

```
Point displayRelativeDrop = new Point(event.x, event.y);
```

Your `fillRectangle` must use points which are relative to the Control (paintC) **not** the display. Use `Control.toControl(point)` to convert from display relative to control relative.

You should also not try to draw the control in the `drop` method. Just call `redraw` on the control and do the drawing in a paint listener.

Comment: Yes I use it with displayRelativePos2. But my rectangle didn't appear. I have the drag position and the drop position but it seems that my drop target event never happen

Comment: Your code does not use the DropTargetEvent x and y.

Comment: Are you talking about this? 
            displayRelativePos2 = dropTarget.getDisplay().getCursorLocation(); I don't know how use redraw going to find something about this

Comment: I am saying you use the x and y values in the DropTargetEvent - added code to the answer.

Comment: I've tried this but it still not work with displayRelativeDrop. I think the event dropTarget never happen

Comment: Yes it's this. The dropTarget event is never executed

Comment: And call redraw will not give me the position of the cursor when the user release the click. I wanted to use drag and drop in order to make a rectangle. The drag will give me the position of the rectangle and the drop will give me another position in order to have the height and the width. And then draw the rectangle. But i don't find an event witch is like "click release" (Sorry for my bad english i'm french..) And thank you for your help