# SWT mouse UP DOWN location

Tags: java, canvas, swt, mouseevent, paint

I wanted to make an application in order to draw a rectangle like in paint.
I used the event "mouseDown" in order to have the first position, and mouseUp for the second position but it don't works.

I don't know why it don't works (my program crash also with my mouseUp event with nothing in)

Here's my code :

```
Canvas paintC = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
paintC.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
        GC gc = new GC(paintC);

        displayRelativePos2.x = e.x;
        displayRelativePos2.y = e.y;

        hauteur = displayRelativePos2.y - displayRelativePos1.y;
        largeur = displayRelativePos2.x - displayRelativePos1.x;

            gc.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
            gc.fillOval(displayRelativePos1.x , displayRelativePos1.y , 50 , 50);
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            displayRelativePos1.x = e.x;
            displayRelativePos1.y = e.y;

        }
    });
```

And here's the errors :

```
at Fenetre$1.mouseDown(Fenetre.java:148)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:192)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4230)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1491)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1499)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1299)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
at Fenetre.open(Fenetre.java:86)
at Fenetre.main(Fenetre.java:71)
```

How to fix this? Or there is another way to do this? I already tested drag and drop but it don't works too. ([SWT drop cursor position on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581087/swt-drop-cursor-position-on-canvas/34581589?noredirect=1#comment56908577_34581589) )

Comment: _"It doesn't work"_ is insufficient.  Explain what is actually happening, and what you expect to happen, and what you've done to debug.

Comment: I edited, my program close when i release my click. The problem is that I don't know how to debug this. It should work I think.. (If i only use mouseDown and i draw a random rectangle it works. But the mouseUp event make crash my program)

Comment: Can you mention the actual error as well? Just a stack trace won't give much idea.

Comment: I have no errors, only warning for unused var or imports. My program crash when few second after my click (and not released)

Comment: What is the line before the 'at Fenetre$1....' message? Which is line 148?

Comment: There is this after "Canvas paintC = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
                paintC.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {"